# Doesn't Cygwin provide the "more" command?

Tags: cygwin

It's not available in my Cygwin. The "less" command is provided, on the other hand. Maybe the makers of Cygwin think that "more" is just redundant.

I'm curious about that.

Comment: Personally, I find `less` better than `more`.  And there are ways to configure `less` to act more like `more` and less like `less`, more or less.  But in any case, `more` is available.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Install the util-linux package and you will have "more"

http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=util-linux%2Futil-linux-2.17.2-1

Comment: i accidently did rm -r /usr (did ctrl+C in between though) and lost more. But apt-cyg install util-linux helped. Still wondering what else i lost :(

Answer (score 2):

it does - type `which more` and you'll get something like this:

`/usr/bin/more`

If the more command is [not available](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2004-12/msg00145.html), you could define a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Cygwin_symbolic_links) to `/usr/bin/less`, or define an alias. I have Cygwin v1.7.9 installed with literally everything included, it's possible that you have an older version partially installed that doesn't supply more. You can find out what version, you're using like so:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 ws-02615 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) 2011-03-29 10:10 i686 Cygwin
```

Comment: if you get nothing, then you may not have installed it when you installed cygwin.

Comment: It is in the [unix-utils](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=bin%2Fmore) package. The link is actually a search in cygwin through package contents. A little slow, but it gets there.

Comment: Thanks, all. Interestingly, my Cygwin version is the current 1.7.9, but the more.exe isn't installed, and it can be found in neither the packages "Utils", "Text", nor "Doc".

Comment: From which mirror site did you download your Cygwin, please?

Comment: All right. I've found the "more" utility. It's in the utils-linux package of Cygwin. See this related question: http://superuser.com/questions/237476/do-all-linux-commands-exist-in-cygwin .

Comment: Looks like it is under (System|Text|Utils)/util-linux (not utils-linux, at least on my mirror)

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin's installer setup.exe has a search box which allows you to search for utilities you need. Unfortunately this doesn't work if the utility is included in a Cygwin Package in this case you need to use the online search provided here:-

https://cygwin.com/packages/

More is in util-linux (see @joseph) which you can install by typing util-linux into the setup.exe search box (or just linux)

the other package I always need is cygutils-extra as it includes putclip & getclip